# Generalizing two similar functions into one

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, decode, encode

So below is a bit of Python code which is able to encode and decode sentences. I'm not sure how to define a function that takes three parameters that can generalize or combine the two functions: mapInToOutEncode and mapInToOutDecode into one.

```
alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
keyString ="kjihgfedcba zyxwvutsrqponml"

def mapInToOutEncode(inChar):
    index = 0
    found = 0
    for char in alphabet:
        if(char == inChar):
            found = index #remember it in a variable found
        else:
            index +=1
    outChar = keyString[found]
    return(outChar)

def mapInToOutDecode(inChar):
    index = 0
    found = 0
    for char in alphabet:
        if(char == inChar):
            found = index #remember it in a variable found
        else:
            index +=1
    outChar = keyString[found]
    return(outChar)

def encode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOutEncode(char)
    return(outString)

def decode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOutDecode(char)
    return(outString)

print( encode("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn" ))
print( decode(encode("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn")))
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer to "how to combine the functions", but the functionality you're looking for is already implemented in [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), see also [`string.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your functions `mapInToOutEncode` and `mapInToOutDecode` are identical. In order to get the functionality you're aiming to, `mapInToOutDecode` should have been:

```
def mapInToOutDecode(inChar):
    index = 0
    found = 0
    for char in keyString:
        if(char == inChar):
            found = index #remember it in a variable found
            break
        else:
            index +=1
    outChar = alphabet[found]
    return(outChar)
```

Note that I also added the word `break`, so your code doesn't keep looking for `inchar` once it has found it.

Now, to get what you want (a generalized function for `mapInToOutEncode` and `mapInToOutDecode`) you could have:

```
def mapInToOut(inChar, alphFrom, alphTo):
    index = 0
    found = 0
    for char in alphFrom:
        if(char == inChar):
            found = index #remember it in a variable found
            break
        else:
            index +=1
    outChar = alphTo[found]
    return(outChar)
```

To **encode** each char `a`, you would use `mapInToOut(a, alphabet, keyString)`. To **decode** each char `b`, you would use `mapInToOut(b, keyString, alphabet)`.

So, the `encode` and `decode` functions would look like this:

```
def encode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOut(char, alphabet, keyString)
    return(outString)

def decode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOut(char, keyString, alphabet)
    return(outString)
```

---

Here is a **complete** working example (i.e., this should be your whole code):

```
alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
keyString ="kjihgfedcba zyxwvutsrqponml"

def mapInToOut(inChar, alphFrom, alphTo):
    index = 0
    found = 0
    for char in alphFrom:
        if(char == inChar):
            found = index #remember it in a variable found
            break
        else:
            index +=1
    outChar = alphTo[found]
    return(outChar)

def encode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOut(char, alphabet, keyString)
    return(outString)

def decode(inString):
    outString = ''
    for char in inString:
        outString += mapInToOut(char, keyString, alphabet)
    return(outString)

print ("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn")
encoded_msg = encode("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn")
print encoded_msg
print decode(encoded_msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out! When I change the keyString in "outChar = keyString[found]" into alphabet, the output I get from encode and decode are exactly the same now! And also when I run it with your changes, it says "NameError: global name 'alpFrom' is not defined"....?

Comment: That is when I print( encode("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn" )) and 
print( decode(encode("this is a crazy bit of news to share we attack at dawn"))), I get rcbskbskjkhtjlmkibrkwekxfoskrwkscjtfkofkjrrjh kjrkgjox for both print statements....

Comment: I didn't write `alpFrom` anywhere. Are you copying my code with `ctrl+c , ctrl+v' or retyping it? I think you might be copying it wrong. Make sure your code is exactly like mine (that also goes for your other question).

Comment: It's not working...so I have the mapInToOut part, and I also kept the def encode(inString) and the def decode(inString) part, do I change my for loop into "outString += mapInToOut(char,alphabet,keyString)" ?

Comment: I edited my code to clarify it better. It's working, I've just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary to do your encoding/decoding, it will greatly simplify your code:

```
>>> alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> keyString ="kjihgfedcba zyxwvutsrqponml"
>>> encoder = dict(zip(alphabet, keyString))
>>> decoder = dict(zip(keyString, alphabet))
>>> a = 'this is a string'
>>> q = ''.join(encoder.get(i, i) for i in a)
>>> q
'rcbskbskjksrtbxd'
>>> ''.join(decoder.get(i, i) for i in q)
'this is a string'
```